# Flask cannot see form

Tags: python, flask, leaflet

I'm trying to build a simple application using Leaflet in Flask, but I have a problem with the form. I want to send data from the form to my database but when I use the POST method, Flask doesn't want to read this method. When I used only GET, all values were empty in the database. When i used POST and GET nothing happened, none of the rows were added to the database.

forms.py

```
class EventForm(FlaskForm):
    date_start = DateField(validators=[DataRequired()])
    date_end = DateField(validators=[DataRequired()])
    type = StringField(validators=[DataRequired()])
    name = StringField(validators=[DataRequired()])
    len_route = FloatField(validators=[DataRequired()])
```

mapa.html with Leaflet map and the form

```
<div id="fields">
                    <form action="" method="post">
                        <input type="text" id="route_len"  class="form-control mb-2" name="route_len_input" placeholder="Długosc trasy">
                        <br>
                        <button id="draw-button"  class="btn btn-success">Rysuj trase</button>
                        <br><br>
                        <input type="text" id="name"  class="form-control mb-2" name="name_input" placeholder="Nazwa">
                        <br>
                        <input type="datetime-local" id="date_st" class="form-control mb-2" required name="date_st_input" placeholder="Data startu">
                        <br>
                        <input type="datetime-local" id="date_end" class="form-control mb-2" required name="date_end_input" placeholder="Data końcowa">
                        <br>
                        <select  id="type" class="form-control mb-2" name="type_input">
                            <option></option>
                            <option value="Bieganie">Bieganie</option>
                            <option value="Rower">Rower</option>
                            <option value="Nordic walking">Nordic Walking</option>
                        </select>
                        <br>
                        <button type="submit"  id="end-button" name="sub" class="btn btn-danger">Zakończ rysowanie</button>
                        <br><br>
                    </form>
 </div>
```

routes.py

```
@app.route('/mapaa',methods=["GET","POST"])
def mapa():
    if request.method == "POST":
        data_pocz = request.form['date_st_input']
        data_kon = request.form['date_end_input']
        nazwa = request.form['name_input']
        typ = request.form['type_input']
        dlugosc = request.form['route_len_input']
        event_database = Event(date_start=data_pocz, date_end=data_kon, type=typ, name=nazwa, len_route=dlugosc)
        db.session.add(event_database)
        db.session.commit()
    return render_template('mapaa.html', title='Mapa')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should link the form to your flask method

```
<form method="POST" action="/mapaa"> [...]
```

Comment: you should debug and see what format is the data you receive...  add a breakpoint before the __if__. import pdb; pdb.set_trace() and print your request... do some debugging

Comment: I tried request.method and this function returned only GET. Values of all variables are None. Still cannot see form and request POST.

Comment: Don't know if this is a real thing, but make sure you close the inputs: add a / at the end. e.g. <input type="number" name="tllat" placeholder="TopLeftLat" required/>

Comment: Unfortunately this dosen't work. I don't know what is wrong I tried everything and still I don't see any mistakes :/

Comment: Random idea: try without special characters in the text e.g. without ł

Comment: If you'll put your code on github, i could take a look on the structure of your files & try help

Comment: Also ! make sure you force refresh your cache on the browser... cmd+shift+r or ctrl+shift+r, so the browser reloads the html from the server and does not reuse an old cached version

Comment: I found a problem. The problem is in js code. Thank you for all your comments ;)

Comment: Congretz! What was it?

Comment: I have programmed this button in js function and apparently when I set as submit button something is wrong. I dont found exact solution but I know now where to find it.  I added another submit button in form and when I click it everything work fine. Something is wrong in js code with function.